how to send sqs message via jmeter , and what name should be given to key "endpointConfiguration"
Ignoring queue with name 'sqs-queue': The queue does not exist.; nested exception is com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.QueueDoesNotExistException: The specified queue does not exist for this wsdl version. (Service: AmazonSQS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AWS.SimpleQueueService.NonExistentQueue;
I've verified that the queue exists in the AWS Management Console and that I have the necessary permissions. When I run a program that includes the key endpointConfiguration, it works perfectly. However, without specifying this key in JMeter, I get the above error.
Here's what I've tried so far:
Double-checked the queue name for typos.
Verified the queue's existence in the correct AWS region.
Confirmed that my IAM user has the necessary permissions for accessing SQS.
Used the correct AWS SDK version in my program.
Question:
How can I configure JMeter to include the endpointConfiguration when sending messages to SQS? Are there specific settings or additional plugins required to resolve this error?
Additional Context:
I'm using the AWS SQS Plugin for JMeter.
The program that works correctly includes the following configuration for SQS client initialization:

To me the context is not clear. I think that you should describe what you are trying to achieve and share some code or screenshots of your JMeter setup with the mentioned plugin and mention the moment when the error is received.

I don't know what "AWS SQS Plugin for JMeter" is, if it's something developed by your company in-house you should reach out to the plugin's developers and/or maintainers and ask them.
The public "AWS Support" plugin doesn't have any "endointConfiguration"

so it worth checking out documentation on SQS and give it a try
The plugin can be installed using JMeter Plugins Manager

In general the reasons for the "QueueDoesNotExistException" are in:

incorrect queue name (or it's not present in the given region
your account doesn't have permissions for the queue
the WSDL version for the SQS service is not correct

